# How to use onpopstate, with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have a website that has 4 main pages, index, somepage, someotherPage, and LastOtherpage.
They have different names, like index.php, food_and_health.php, enlightening_info.php, and about_us.php.

I have my ajax part(HTTPrequest) working fine, and the pushstate is working.

What I now want, is obviously, the popstate function working.
I have read, and watched tutorials, but how would I do this with the this keyword?

I have a fiddle added, so you can see me code, its not working well in the fiddle, but works very good in chrome, firefox and late ie.
I have something like this in mind for my onpopstate..

```
nav.history("this.object", "Title", "/this.url"); 
http://jsfiddle.net/vwd6bnjc/1/
```

How would the onpopstate code look like?
I know it is bad to ask for all the code, but this way I actually learn, as when I read the code, I understand it. I haven't fully got the grip of javascript eventhandling yet, as you can see I use onclick in my html documentes, and not eventhandling them.
But this I know, I can do, it is just a lot of changing in my documents, and first priority for me, would be to have back/forward, refresh, and share functionality to work, so that I can actually share my website out in the web, without and lack of functionality! :)

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I used ajax in a similar way your suggesting. I took advantage of the `history.pushState()` state object. The history object doesn't allow access to history session urls(it's reasonably a security risk). I simulated the effect by storing the requested URL in the state object.

I have viewed your example on jsfiddle and will be using it for reference.

I suggest when using `history.pushState` in your `function Mat(url)` to add `url` parameter to the state object like so.

```
history.pushState({urlRequested:url}, 'Page Title');
```

It's good to remember that when using `pushState` method and supplying a URL for the third argument will also cause the browser URL address to change. So if you refresh the page you will be requesting the updated URL. How you handle this is up to you but by excluding it the current document location will be used. So if the page is refreshed the requested page will be the same.

After supplying a state object the `event.state` property will have the object `[urlRequested:url]` which can be use to get the url.

To accomplish this you might do something like so.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
    if (event.state !== null) {
        /**
         * Here you can code what operations you want to accomplish
         * when the event is called. If you would like you can use
         * your function Mat( url )
         */
        Mat(event.state['urlRequested']);
        //this gets the value of urlRequested which is the URL
    }
}, true);
```

When a user navigates between two history entries the `onpopstate` event is fired. When that happens your `function Mat( url )` will be pass the URL stored in the `state` propert and sent an ajax request using the URL.

I sure hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: very helpful, that must be what I am looking for, will try it out! Thanks for a well explained answer, and for an alternative wat to add url.
I think, that it suits me best to have url as the third argument, as I want different url's for my page. Otherwise I would only have 4 different url's, right?  And for sharing pages, and navigating back and forward, it seems more logic to have different url's, so that people can navigate directly to the page if they i.e. bookmark it, or share to a friend. I can then look into changing title, and og:titles:)
I will play around with it a bit :) Thanks!

Comment: I understand from your code here the way to use onpopstate. Still, it has no effect other then messing up my page :/
As I tried to specify, I need to be able to navigate back and forward, loading the correct page, that would be, somehtmlpage/someajaxpage.php, and when going to someOtherHtmlpage, and back to somehtmlpage/someajaxpage.php, that ajaxpage should be loaded, not the html page only. I therefore need unique url/href's, also this looks better for the user.
I will also need to be able to refresh the page, and have the ajaxpage load with styling. Maybe I should just use jQuery..

Comment: In firefox, it will now go to the html page, and ignore the ajax.
in chrome it will load the ajax without styling.
If you need to see it better, go check out www.sunto.no/english.
The top menu's are html, except the enviroment part, wich is another page embedded.

Answer (score 1):

If MDN did not help you, you can look at history.js and use that for cross-browser, or look and see how onPopState is used:

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: history.js is jQuery, is it not? Will look it up ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does the examples from MDN help you? Have you had a chance to look at that?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: Yes, I have read that, but the ajax example there includes json, and as I understood, or misunderstood, I am only missing the onpopstate eventhandler.
As it is now, when I navigate from index.php, to someOtherPage.php, and from there use ajax to open a menu item, say someOtherPage.php/ajaxPage, when I then navigate to SomeOtherHtmlPageNotWithAjax.php, and go back to someOtherPage.php, it will show the loaded ajax content, like SomeOtherPage.php/ajaxPage
But another back click, will not change anything, it should be changed to someOtherPage.php with 2nd click on backbutton,

Comment: Also, if I refresh someOtherPage.php/ajaxPage, the page will be loaded without style. This I understand is because I am missing the onpopstate eventhandler.
What I do not fully understand, is how to use onpopstate, when I have 3 different html pages, using ajax in all of them. And to set uo the onpopstate function correctly. More studying is needed, I know, on eventhandling, but cannot find the tutorials i need, many show with jQuery, and that I do not use.